# Probability that a system of linear inequalities of random variables is satisfied

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables, systems-of-equations

Let $X_i$ (i = 1...n) be a set of independent uniform random variables. Is there a tool/method/concept to find the probability that a system of linear inequalities of $X_i$ is satisfied ?

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
 a_1 < b_{11} X_1 + b_{12} X_2 + ... + b_{1n} X_n < c_1 \\ 
 ... \\
 a_j < b_{j1} X_1 + b_{j2} X_2 + ... + b_{jn} X_n < c_j \\ 
 ... \\
 a_m < b_{m1} X_1 + b_{m2} X_2 + ... + b_{mn} X_n < c_m
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
with $a_j, b_{ji}, c_j \in R$

For a single inequality, one can find the probability using convolution.

For several inequalities and $n < 4$, one can find the probability using a geometric method.

But what if $n \geqslant 4$ ?

**Edit**: maybe some will prefer solving a practical example, here is one:

Let $W, X, Y, Z$ be independent uniform random variables on [0, 1]. What is the probability that the next conditions are satisfied?

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
 1 < X + 2Y + 3Z < 5 \\ 
 2 < W + 3X + 4Z < 7 \\
 1 < 2W + X + 2Y + 3Z < 6
\end{array}
\right. 
$$